# Are there Graphic Designers that only do logos?

Tags: logo, terminology

I'm not sure what all a Graphic Designer does.  If it is like someone saying they "work on computers," it can mean anything, but is there such a thing as a designer that only does Logos?  Does that branch of design have a "special" name?  Just "logo design" or something?

Edit:  Is making logos also called "Branding"?

Comment: Unlikely that a graphic designer would limit themselves in such a way. Usually it's the client that decides what they want.

Answer (score 2):

It is rather unlikely, as clients with logo needs often have a marketing strategy problem so what they are in fact looking for is a corporate visual language (that is part of branding, logo making is a minuscule part of that). And so you would end up designing things other than logos if you're any good.

But if you're not good you don't get to design logos. Also you wont get these jobs immediately either so a designer that is only working on logos for their whole career would be nearly impossible.